Can I increase the wattage of my landcruiser plug?
I have a landcruiser / prado (2020) in Europe with a plug in the back that has 220V and 150W. Can I somehow increase this wattage to 800-1000W so I can plug in a spot removal machine?
My car has 2 batteries, so I feel like it should be able to output some power. I am not sure if its LiFePo4 or lead-acid or something else.
Is an inverter able to do that? Will this damage the batteries in any way? How do I limit the damage to the battery (for example not deep discharging).
I just want to run it for 30-60 minutes.
Why did they put a plug in with such high voltage, that can't even run a rice cooker? Its basically the same wattage as the lighter plug in the front.

Can your spot removal machine run on 12V or 24V DC ?  You might be able to avoid the losses of double conversion in the first place.

1000W would drain a typical car battery (50Ah) completely flat in half an hour. You may be underestimating what you're asking of your vehicle's electrical system.

@Criggie I am not sure, it might. It doesn't say on the website what the voltage is.

1000W at 12V is more than 80 amps. I'd run 2AWG wire which is quite beefy. To be clear I have run 2AWG from my engine bay to the back of my truck to supply 100A back there. The intent was to supply the 100A only when the engine was running though. I have seen some overlanders running 400Ah or more systems capable of running espresso machines and whatnot, but those aren't on for very long.

If you're using a spot removal machine, what other high-power devices are you using? If it is only to clean the vehicle interior, have you considered some sort of lining that you can remove and clean with water?

@AndrewMorton a lining that would block dirt could also block air? I am not sure if that would be comfortable. But yes, modifying the car just for that seems overkill.

@user1721135 I was imagining that you might be using it to clean the boot (trunk), for which you could get a dirt-proof liner.

@AndrewMorton what If I simply get jumper cable type cables and an external inverter and just run the engine and connect to the car batteries?

Yes, you can, BUT:

The pair of batteries in LandCruiser (in theory) contains ~1800Wh of energy, of them the usable amount is ~700Wh. If your load is e.g. 700W, this amounts to running it for less than 1 hour.


These batteries really don't like to be deeply discharged. Deep-cycle batteries do exist, but at a price.
Modern cars tend to keep their batteries in 50-70% state-of-charge for fuel economy reasons. This also limits the available energy.
You have to be able to start your engine. This requires ~15% of the energy in the batteries left. The more, the better, esp. as the batteries age.


An option is to leave the engine running while using the electricity. You may not like the exhaust fumes around.
You will need a way bigger than the original inverter, mounted somewhere near the batteries. In a tightly-packed engine compartment of a modern car, this can prove challenging. The car warrranty may suffer as well.
An ampere-hour counting battery monitor is also advisable.


In other words its not a good idea. Maybe I should just get a gas generator? Sounds simple and cheap.

@user1721135 it depends on your use pattern. While I am not sure why you would run this particular thing off a car power, it is pretty much possible to alter your car for more electrical power. The gas generator has its own issues - e.g. noise, exhaust, maintenance and fuel.

@user1721135 That would definitely be the simpler solution. Not only do you have to check the power your car can generate, all the wiring between the generation and the plug (incl. the plug itself) have to be rated for that power as well.

@fraxinus in my area I don't have electricity near my car, I don't have a house and the cleaning places for self cleaning don't offer plugs. Maybe I can pay someone to do this for me, its not very complicated it seems? Since the car has to be running anyway it probably won't deep drain the batteries anyway.

@user1721135 800W at 12V is some 70-80A (before factoring in inverter losses, so even more in reality). That's quite a lot of current, going to kill the battery soon if you leave the engine off. It's still going to be tough on the batteries and the whole electrical system in the car even with the engine running. My wild ballpark guess is that the alternator in your car is rated to deliver something like 100A, and quite a bit of that is consumed by the engine itself (ECU, ignition, fuel pump, etc.). So you will be draining the battery even with the alternator working hard (if the ECU lets you).

@TooTea But the idea to let the engine run (terrible as it is efficiency-wise) is good, I think. In any case you don't want to run a 1kW appliance longer than 10 minutes or so off your battery.

@user1721135 Yes, generator or a proper heavy duty RV (solar and-or generator)/battery/inverter set.  For 1kW a regular (starter) battery is simply not the right power source. Too much current. It will work for a few minutes if you must.

Yes, you could theoretically run a higher wattage connection to run your spot removal machine. Can you do it to the outlet you are trying to utilize right now? Not without a new inverter and new wiring (thicker gauge) from the battery. You'd be better off to leave what is there in place and run new wiring and a stronger inverter. You'd also want to run the vehicle while doing this, because an automotive 12v system with wet lead/acid batteries in it doesn't really have that much reserve capacity, nor will it stand up to the constant charge/discharge cycles they'd be put through. You need deep cycle batteries for this.
A much better option would be to get some type of portable power bank which can be charged separately and then used as needed. The main reason I say this is, if you, for some reason believe you can run the spot remover off of the batteries in the vehicle and then get a little carried away and completely run your batteries out of power, you'd be left stranded. A portable battery bank may run out of power, but if it were to happen, you'd still have battery power in your lead/acid batteries to start the car.

II checked some power banks with 1000W but they are pretty expensive. I think I might opt for gas powered generator instead. Can I not buy an ínverter which plugs into the plug and outputs 1000W or it doesn't work like that?

@user1721135 If your 12V power plug has a 10 amp fuse the maximum inverter watts is about 120W. A 20 amp fuse, 240W. For 1000W your battery current will be more than 80 amps, which you must get by wiring direct to the battery, not by using clamps. That is a total dead end. Rent a portable generator. A 1-day rental of a 2000W generator costs less than half as much as buying a 1000W inverter.

@MTA my plug is 220v and 150W does that change anything?

@user1721135 No, that doesn't change anything. Watts are watts no matter what the voltage. The fuse for your inverter is probably 15 amps and good for 180W to the inverter and 150W to the inverter's 220V outlet.

"You'd be better off to leave what is there in place and run new wiring and a stronger inverter. You'd also want to run the vehicle while doing this" -- perhaps clarify that you don't mean running the vehicle while installing the new inverter, but while using the new inverter. :)


Why did they put a plug in with such high voltage, that can't even run a rice cooker?

I suspect the reason is so people can charge their electronic gadgets, particularly laptops, easily.
Laptop charging was until recently, a mess of different connectors (some standard some proprietary) and proprietary methods of signalling to the laptop how much power the supply could deliver. "Car chargers" running of 12V did exist, both units specific to one manufacturers charging system, and "Universal" units with a bunch of interchangeable tips, one of which might suit your laptop but they weren't something most people owned and unless you made careful comparisons beforehand it was far from gauranteed that a "universal" charger would work with any particular laptop.
In recent years, USB C has helped improve the situation but it's still far from ideal. USB C has many different modes voltage/current combinations. Virtually any USB charging port will charge a phone or tablet (though sometimes slowly), but laptops tend to be fussier about what modes they will accept. A basic USB C cable will only support up to 60W (20V 3A), higher power modes require special "electronically marked" cables. There are also still many laptops in use that don't support USB C charging.
All this is to say that often the easiest way to charge a laptop in a car was and to some extent still is, to use an inverter to step the cars voltage up to "mains" and then to use the power supply that came with the laptop to step that back down to what the laptop wants. Still a separate inverter, and a heavy cord to power it
An obvious way to make this even easier and more convenient for customers is to integrate the inverter in the vehicle. Then people can just plug in their laptop without buying any special stuff.
Larger inverters absolutely do exist, but they cost more, take up more space and require heavier cables to supply them (and connect them to the outlet if the outlet is not part of the inverter). Use of a larger inverter may also require installing larger batteries and a larger alternator to avoid problems with draining the batteries and/or it may require keeping the engine running while using the electrical equipment.
Ultimately, auto vendors have to tread a fine line between providing the features customers want and keeping the cost and fuel-economy of their vehicles in check.
Some EVs now support "vehicle to load", a special adapter is plugged into the charge point on the car, and the charge circuit in the car reconfigures itself as an inverter. This allows high power to be delivered cheaply because it's reusing mostly the same electronics as charging the car, and because the batteries operate at a much higher voltage.

But why only offer 120w thats not even enough for some laptops, I don't get it. They could have made it useful for powertools if they wanted, there are people reporting customizations for increased wattage.

@user1721135 120W is enough for virtually all laptops ever made.  After all they have to be capable of running off their own batteries.  It's not necessarily enough for some modern (i.e. fast) laptop chargers, but don't forget that car design moves more slowly than portable tech design, so at design time they would just ignore the edge case that is high power laptop chargers.  Even with those there's a chance you'll get away with it if you don't try to boot up when the battery is very low
